# access to standalone app with more stable database

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, user-interface, ms-access

Does anyone have experience of rapidly translating an access application into a standalone windows application? My current thoughts are to create an SQL database and a gui in c# and vb, or adobe flex 3.

As with acces, the GUI would mainly comprise of controls such as radio buttons, combo box (populated from a table), check boxes, text boxes, text areas and data grids. It will also need the ability to create reports as access does.

Any advice based would be appreciated.

Happy new year.

Comment: Why?  What problems are you trying to solve?   There's nothing as fast as Access for creating a dataase driven application.   Besides C#, VB.Net or Adobe Flex aren't stand alone systems.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your prompt replies. When I say standalone windows app, I mean an app that can be compiled to run by itself on windows or direct the user to download the appropriate files, such as adobe air. 

Most of the reason I'm doing this is because I created a prototype with access and now wish to distribute the software so that it is not computationaly feasible for others reverse engineer the software.

Comment: I forgot to add that a number of frontends will need to access the same database, but only over an intranet.

Comment: Are you aware that the workset for an Access runtime app is pretty much equivalent to that for a compiled VB app? I can't imagine that C# or anything else on the CLR would require *less* in the way of workset than standard VB, so Access is not really going to be much different in terms of the support environment that will be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use the upsize wizard (tools menu) to port the data to SQL Server
- Carry on using Access as a front end
- Change the schema as needed, hide change behind views for Access
- Write a new GUI in asp.net or WinForms

Comment: Although I wouldn't bother with the writing of a new GUI in another app.  After all you can't consider C#, VB.Net or Adobe Flex to be stand alone systems.

Answer (score 1):

[sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) may be the choice of database. It is simple, a self-contained, embeddable, zero-configuration SQL database engine. you don't need any database server as sqlite is file-based.

I guess vb.net 2008 can be used as it is very easy to generate GUI.

Comment: And the application part? That's by far the more complicated issue here. Your doesn't doesn't address the most important part of the question at all.